# Issue in ear deployment in jboss 6.3 eap linux environment

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I am having an issue while deploying ear in JBOSS 6.3 EAP UAT under Linux environment. The same ear i can able to deploy in local Windows and Linux environments with out any errors.But in UAT it is creating problem with xmlparserv2.jar.If i remove this jar application deployed successfully.
Since application is using xmlparserv2.jar it can not be removed.Below is the error captured in server log.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/collections]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) JBWEB000289: Servlet cxf threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLComment cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
at java.util.XMLUtils.importProperties(XMLUtils.java:114) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:86) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:868) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:71) [cxf-common-utilities-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.registerInitialExtensions(WSDLManagerImpl.java:224) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.registerInitialExtensions(WSDLManagerImpl.java:219) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.<init>(WSDLManagerImpl.java:109) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429) [spring-beans-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729) [spring-context-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) [spring-context-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.<init>(BusApplicationContext.java:91) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringBusFactory.java:102) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:93) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:86) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:64) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:53) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.updateContext(CXFServlet.java:117) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadSpringBus(CXFServlet.java:101) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:70) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.init(AbstractCXFServlet.java:90) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

I would request you to help in this,Thanks.

Comment: version of java in UAT is java version "1.7.0_45" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15) and version of local is java version "1.7.0_85" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.1.2.0.1.el7_1-x86_64 u85-b01)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a reported [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7099658) and fixed, try to upgrade your java version

```
Fixed Versions:

6u29-rev (b22)
```

Comment: our jdk env is java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)